# How to join a generic list of objects on a specific property

Tags: c#, .net, list

```
 class Person
 {
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
 }

 List<Person> theList = populate it with a list of Person objects
```

How can I get a string which contains all the FirstName of the objects in the list separated by a comma. Eg:
John,Peter,Jack

A basic solution would be to iterate through each object but I'm sure there is a one-line solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update (as of .NET 4)**
[`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) now has an overload which takes an `IEnumerable<string>` - yay!

```
string.Join(",", theList.Select(p => p.FirstName));
```

*For .NET versions **below 4.0** (older)*:

```
string.Join(",", theList.ConvertAll(person => person.FirstName).ToArray());
```

Breaking it down into component parts:

`List<T>.ConvertAll` converts a `List<T>` to another type - in this case a `List<string>`.

`ToArray()` converts the `List<string>` to a `string[]`.

`string.Join()` writes an array of strings (the second parameter) as a single string, separated by the first parameter.

Comment: How does the solution "Update (as of .NET 4)", join only the FirstNames?

Comment: The .NET 4 solution does need a select: `String.Join(",", theList.Select(p => p.FirstName));`

Answer (score 6):

You could also use a query extension method

```
string output = theList.Select(p => p.FirstName).Aggregate((progress, next) => progress + ", " + next);
```

This will avoid having to create an array.